how to get key press in while loop without stopping the loop c
I have a game where I need to constantly get the keyboard input, and clear the screen and draw the screen at the same time. This is in the terminal.
I have tried using khbit() and getting the keys with getch(), but getch() keeps stopping the game loop (while loop). Is there any way to get keys input without stopping the while loop?
This is that part of the code:
char ch;

void keyInput(){
    if (kbhit) {
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == 'x' || ch == 'X'){
            cls();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    srand(time(0));

    while(1){
        chooseType();
        cls();
        screen(); 
    
        keyInput();

        Sleep(100);
    }
    

    return 0;
}

cls() being clearing the terminal, and screen() drawing some asciii stuff. Ignore chooseType()

By using kbhit() and getch(). Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem with a simple loop.

Error here: if (kbhit) should be if (kbhit()). You are not calling the function, and its address won't be NULL, therefore your code unconditionally calls getch(), which blocks.

Also, getch returns an int, not a char, so that you can check for errors.

Yes, take note of the return type from all those "character" input functions. Don't confuse "character" with char. This 'a' has type int, not char.
